# Check if character is from given set, if possible using enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I want to check whether character stored in variable char c is from { 'a' , 'b', 'c', '1', '3', '5', '7', '9' }.

Of corse I can do it in following way:

if (c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == '1' || c == '3' || c == '5' || c == '7' || c == '9') {
//do something...
}

If I check this for variable c and different sets of allowed characters in different places in my Java program, I'll get too awkward code.
I'm looking for simpler one.

Comment: _Any implementation_ Any attempt from your end?

Comment: The most concise way is `if ("abc13579".indexOf(c) >= 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to hold a set of allowed characters:

```
private static final Set<Character> ALLOWED = 
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a' , 'b', 'c', '1', '3', '5', '7', '9'));

public static final boolean isAllowed(char c) {
    return ALLOWED.contains(c);
}
```